# Using Go channels to speed up for loop

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I'm trying to use Go's concurrency to speed up my code,

Here's what I have:

```
            for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
                go func (ch chan int32, ch2 chan int32, i int, arx int32, ary int32, dirf []int8, dirg []int8) {
                    nx := arx + int32(dirf[i])
                    ny := ary + int32(dirg[i])
                    ch <- nx
                    ch2 <- ny

                }(ch, ch2, i, arx,ary,dirf,dirg)

            }
            for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
                nxx := <- ch
                nyx := <- ch2
                ind := nyx*w+nxx
                if imData[ind] == e[i]{
                    process[c]=nxx
                    process[c+1]=nyx
                    c+=2
                    matrix[ind]=1
                }
            }
```

After running this I'm not getting the matrix slice that I expected, it's full of zeros.

But if I run the code below, it gives the matrix slice just as the code without channels but it's too slow.

```
            for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
                go func (ch chan int32, ch2 chan int32, i int, arx int32, ary int32, dirf []int8, dirg []int8) {
                    nx := arx + int32(dirf[i])
                    ny := ary + int32(dirg[i])
                    ch <- nx
                    ch2 <- ny

                }(ch, ch2, i, arx,ary,dirf,dirg)
                nxx := <- ch
                nyx := <- ch2
                ind := nyx*w+nxx
                if imData[ind] == e[i]{
                    process[c]=nxx
                    process[c+1]=nyx
                    c+=2
                    matrix[ind]=1
                }
            }
```

What's wrong with the first one? Any ideas? I'm very new at Go. So, please be clear when you are suggesting something.

Edit:
I edited the code to have values in proper order,

```
type data struct {
    i int
    nx int32
    ny int32
}

           for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
                go func (ch chan data, i int, arx int32, ary int32, dirf []int8, dirg []int8) {
                    nx := arx + int32(dirf[i])
                    ny := ary + int32(dirg[i])
                    ch <- data{i,nx,ny}

                }(ch, i, arx,ary,dirf,dirg)

            }
            for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
                d := <- ch
                nxx := d.nx
                nyx := d.ny
                j := d.i
                ind := nyx*w+nxx
                if imData[ind] == e[j]{
                    process[c]=nxx
                    process[c+1]=nyx
                    c+=2
                    matrix[ind]=1
                }
            }
```

It works now but it's still too slow.

I'm trying to speed up this main code:

```
for i:=7; i>-1; i-- {
        nx := arx + int32(dirf[i])
        ny := ary + int32(dirg[i])
        ind := ny*w+nx
        if imData[ind] == e[i]{
            process[c]=nx
            process[c+1]=ny
            c+=2
            matrix[ind]=1
        }
    }
```

what do you suggest with that?

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you're certain that the goroutines are executed "in the right order", since you wait for goroutines to complete before you continue on to the next one.

An example would be [this minimal example](https://play.golang.org/p/xF3eoK9RzZ) on the golang playground. To fix this, you probably want pass a struct of three members, your `nx`, `ny` and `i` values across the channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it made the code work but still too slow, I updated the question, can you look at it also?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting your "if imData[ind] == e[i]" conditional is failing in the former case, but it's hard to tell without the setup code for the channels, and more details on what those various slices hold.  Have you tried running it with a print statement to see what you get from the channels?

Also, note that if the channels in question are buffered, there's no guarantee that the values in `ch` and `ch2` are going to be in the same order.  This is very possibly your issue.

Goroutine 1 could put a value on `ch`, but Goroutine 2 could have put a value on `ch2` before Goroutine 1 gets to it.  If you have 7 goroutines, it's perfectly possible to see the following ordering on the channels (or any number of others):

`ch`: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

`ch2`: 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2

If they aren't buffered, this isn't possible with your code, but it's still technically unsafe (edit: actually, it still won't match up with `i` in the second loop).  If the data is a set of ordered pairs, you should be sending each pair as a structure over a single channel.

Incidentally, you only need to pass variables to the `go func()` call if they are expected to change outside that call.  `ch`, `ch2`, `arx`, `ary`, `dirf`, and `dirg` all appear to be effectively constant for this block of code, and thus don't need to be passed into that `go func()`.  You only need to pass in `i`, because the loop changes it immediately after firing the enclosure into a goroutine.

Now, from a pure speed perspective, you're probably better off moving the first loop inside the `go func()` call.  Instead of creating 7 goroutines while looping in the main routine, you can fire a single routine, and it will loop over the values and send them on the channels.  If the channels are buffered to at least that size, this becomes a VERY fast operation.  Incidentally, this also solves the issue with channel ordering (though it's still better to send ordered pairs as a structure on a single channel), since you only have a single goroutine trying to send on the channels.

Comment: It seems the problem was with order, thanks for answer, but it's still too slow, I updated the question, do you have any idea how to speed up?

Comment: What type of speed are we talking about here?  Have you done any [benchmarking](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/30/how-to-write-benchmarks-in-go)?  The only major speedup I can see would be to not assign the values of `d` to other variables and just use them directly, and if necessary, to pass a pointer to the structures over the channel instead of the structures.  We're starting to play with microsecond benefits here, though.

Comment: The raw version without routines takes ~150ms but the working version with routines takes ~13 seconds.  It doesn't even speed up.

Comment: Ok, there's something else going on, then, because that code alone should take on the order of microseconds to complete.  Example, your code with some fill-ins for the data types and such runs incredibly fast on the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/vhqEHQXwEM

I suspect the slowdown is from some other portion of your program, or something that isn't apparent or present in the code samples above.

Comment: This time measurements are just for the for loop I provided. There is also a upper for loop but I'm using `start2 := time.Now()`,`elapsed2 := time.Since(start2)`,`res += elapsed2`(res is also time duration) to have this measurements. Also, it should be noted that the size of the slices process and matrix are, 44000 and 21712000 respectively. When I set the sizes to these, it doesn't even run, says it took too long.

Comment: With data structures of that size, you're probably running into memory thrash.  Your larger slice, for example, has a data footprint of 21-84 megabytes, depending on whether you're using an `int8` or `int32` for it (could be as much as 168 megabytes, if you're using an `int` on a 64-bit system).  That's well beyond what the cache is capable of handling, and since you're accessing that slice non-sequentially, you can't even take advantage of cache line optimization.

On the note, it might be better to access the first slice from index 0 up instead of the last index down, for the same caching.

Comment: I think the reason you're not seeing speed-up, though, is that you took the least time-limiting portion of your code and tried to put it in a goroutine, which added the innate goroutine overhead (small as it is) without really changing anything as far as your algorithm's bottleneck (the slice accesses).

Have you considered a binary division of work?  Fire a goroutine that processes the first half of the slice, and another for the second half, and each of those recursively split it as well, and so on until it's at a reasonable of elements in each slice?

Comment: So you are saying that concurrency won't help me? I couldn't understand how to do binary division of work with my problem.